# Upgrading Aurora RDS does it automatically adjust the parameters?

Tags: mysql, magento2, amazon-aurora

I am going to upgrade my RDS  for a much bigger instance type (r3.large to r3.2xlarge) and I would like to know if AWS will adjust the mysql parameters accordantly.. what are the may concerns should I have on this procedure? Is fining customization lost when it exist?

```
instance        cpu   Memory    PIOPS-Optimized   Network Performance   
Price
db.r3.large     2     15        No                Moderate              $0.32
db.r3.2xlarge   8     61        Yes               High                  $1.28
```

My main concern is regarding the caching configuration.

innodb_buffer_pool_size is currently 7GB and I thinking about leaving it as 50GB after upgrade. will this be adjusted automatically?

Just to complement the question, I am upgrading due to lack of memory as showed on this:

```
mysql> show status like '%qcache%';
+-------------------------+----------+
| Variable_name           | Value    |
+-------------------------+----------+
| Qcache_free_blocks      | 134      |
| Qcache_free_memory      | 148080   |
| Qcache_hits             | 42459186 |
| Qcache_inserts          | 14059268 |
| Qcache_lowmem_prunes    | 2455035  |
| Qcache_not_cached       | 22422639 |
| Qcache_queries_in_cache | 241632   |
| Qcache_total_blocks     | 772112   |
+-------------------------+----------+
8 rows in set (0.01 sec)
```

As it state mysql cannot cache some stuff and has loads of prunes.

Answer (score 1):

The value of parameter `innodb_buffer_pool_size`, by default, is assigned using the formula `{DBInstanceClassMemory*3/4}`. So if you change the db instance class(*upgrade or downgrade*), then the value is changed accordingly. This is valid as long as you have not changed the value manually and set it to a numeric value(without using the formula).

In your case,If you are upgrading the instance class to a higher class and If you have updated the value of the parameter(without using the formula), then the **same is preserved** after the *db instance class* is upgraded.